# What is the quickest way to add a trello card to the top of a list, rather than bottom?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-lists

What is the quickest way to add a new trello card to the top of a list?

Clicking add to card on the bottom and dragging to the top seems a bit slow

Comment: I wish there was a way to add a card to the top on the iOS Trello App.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Click the list menu (icon appears on hover near the list title) and click "Add Card", which will open the add card dialog at the top instead of the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 18):

You can hover over the top card in a list and press <kbd>N</kbd>

That will cause the card to go in in the #2 slot.

Comment: Not on mobile though :(

Comment: no longer working

Answer (score 15):

When you click to add a card, on the right side of the dialogue that pops up you can see a down arrow. Click that, click "position" and you can select the position from the right side of that prompt.

You can also type your card content like this:

```
    Sample content ^top
```

Then click the "top" prompt that comes up.

Comment: Don't think that one works on mobile either. Drat.

Comment: this is a nice hidden feature. you can also type in `bottom` and numbers to move to other positions.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 - Move right then left

1. <kbd>n</kbd> - Create the new card
2. <kbd>></kbd> - Move the card to the top of the list on the right
3. <kbd><</kbd> - Move the card to the top of the list on the left

### Method 2 - Choose list position when entering title

1. Append  <kbd>^1</kbd> to the title - eg "Email Jane^1"

### Method 3 - List action menu

1. Click "Add Card..." from list action menu and it will insert at the top.
   [image: List action menu]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved by adding "butlerbot" to your board, see detailed description below on how to do it:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/I-want-new-trello-cards-to-be-at-top-of-list-by-default-I-use/qaq-p/725434

Comment: Hi Hannes, could you add a brief summary of what's at the link in the body of your answer, please.  I appreciate that you've mentioned the overall solution to the problem, but if the link goes dead, that minimal information is all anyone will have to refer to.

Comment: @jonsca's case in point, butlerbot was acquired by trello and that link above isn't very helpful. The [acquisition announcement](https://blog.trello.com/trello-acquires-butler) suggests [these butlerbot features](https://trello.com/power-ups/5935cab6b26816f9d49fd814/butler) will have tighter integration, later. Personally, I think butlerbot is overkill and prefer the simpler solutions mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile app you can use move card functionality.

Click card and then three dots on the top right corner. From there choose "move card". This opens a dialog where you can enter a new position.

This way much easier than dragging if the list is long. Hope this helps!